# How to get points from OpenStreetMap of a certain country?

Tags: openstreetmap, area, geocode, country, overpass-api

i'm trying to get the list of all schools in my country, and after several tries i write the following query that works with no errors on http://overpass-turbo.eu:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“amenity=school”=“yes”
*/
[out:json][timeout:60];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=school”
  node[amenity=school]({{geocodeBbox:Italia}});
  way[amenity=school]({{geocodeBbox:Italia}});
  relation[amenity=school]({{geocodeBbox:Italia}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I used `geocodeBbox` to select all schools of Italy because `geocodeId` and `geocodeArea` (please refer to [documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Extended_Overpass_Queries)) give me the following errors:

```
Error: line 10: parse error: ')' expected - '(' found.

Error: line 11: parse error: ')' expected - '(' found.

Error: line 11: parse error: ';' expected - ')' found.

Error: line 12: parse error: ')' expected - '(' found.

Error: line 12: parse error: ';' expected - ')' found.

Error: line 13: parse error: Unknown type ")"

Error: line 13: parse error: An empty query is not allowed

Error: line 13: parse error: Unknown type ";"

Error: line 15: parse error: An empty query is not allowed
```

Anyway the problem is that the query selects even schools that are not in Italy (for example there is a school from Croatia).

So, how to get exactly the points from a certain country?

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/43772/how-to-get-points-of-a-certain-country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Anyway the problem is that the query selects even schools that are not in Italy (for example there is a school from Croatia).

That's correct. A bounding box (bbox) is a rectangle, not a polygon. Therefore it will always include a little bit more, except if you have a rectangle-shaped country that is also perfectly aligned with the given bbox ;)

Try this query instead:

```
[out:json][timeout:600];
// gather results
{{geocodeArea:Italia}}->.searchArea;
(
  // query part for: “amenity=school”
  node[amenity=school](area.searchArea);
  way[amenity=school](area.searchArea);
  relation[amenity=school](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: It collects even nodes without any references to "amenity:school" tag. These nodes contain just type, id, lat and lon tags. Why?

Comment: Because it also collects ways (and relations) tagged with "amenity=school". The geometry of a way is defined by its referenced nodes. For more info read the section about [OSM's basic elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements).

Comment: Do you know any way to get nodes/ways without "duplicates"? I have to parse this data with PHP and i cannot handle recursive data with same node id.

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplicates in the data returned. Maybe your parser is broken. The best is to create a new question, provide the data you are trying to parse, explain us your parser and tell us which data is supposed to be duplicated according to your parser.

Comment: I put "duplicates" between quotes because i mean nodes with no references to the tag (see my previous comment). I would like to get as output just the list of all points (node or way, not both) that have that tag. If i use your OSM query i get node, way and relation that refer to the same point and this output is hard to handle in my PHP parser... (and this creates duplicates)

Comment: Please read my second comment. You don't seem to be very familiar with the basic [OSM elements](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements). These are nodes belonging to "amenity=school" *ways*. These nodes don't also have this tag because that would be redundant. Instead only the way to which these nodes belong to has the amenity tag.

Comment: Yes, i did undestand this and for this reasons i create recursive PHP function to handle it. Then i was guessing that could exist a better way to write the query on OSM to get univocal references to schools. But it seems not to be possible due the basic structure of OSM elements. Thank you anyway ;)