# Open Street Map: how retrieve amenity in Postman?

Tags: get, web-crawler, postman, openstreetmap

Since Google Places API became a hell I'm trying to move to Open Street Map. I'm learning how to call `amenity` with Postman.

For example using this URL I try to retrieve all the toilets in Auckland:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=toilet Auckland
```

But as result I have just 10 `pleace_id` and I'm using `search`.

I think I'm doing things wrong.

1. How can I retrieve **all** toilets in Auckland?
2. Is there any example about how to use `amenity=toilet`, `country=NZ`, `city=Auckland` instead of the generic `search`?

My goal is to improve the precision of my requests.

Comment: Nominatim is a geocoder and not really intended for your use case. Take a look at Overpass API instead.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know that. If this is the right reply and you can add some details you can post it and I will label it as the right one. Thank you

Comment: No time at the moment to write a full answer, sorry. Just use your favorite search engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get points from OpenStreetMap of a certain country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046501/how-to-get-points-from-openstreetmap-of-a-certain-country)

Comment: @mmd, sorry for the misunderstanding. It's not a duplicate, my question was about how to archive it in Postman. Thank you for your care

Comment: Try it out in overpass turbo first. If that works, extract the URL or use the Export. Don't start with Postman, if you're completely unfamiliar with the whole thing.

Comment: cross-post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292163/how-to-query-overpass-api-with-postman

Comment: Take a look at the documentation then: http://overpass-api.de/command_line.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a good and a bad news.

**Good news:** I finally found an [example](https://giswiki.hsr.ch/Overpass_API) about how to query Overpass API and I could retrieve what I think are most of the cinemas in France:

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=area[name=France];node(area)[amenity=cinema];out;
```

[image]

(I still don't get how to insert `way` and `rel` into the call)

**Bad News:** apparently there are no cinemas in Italy:

[image]

Tanks a million to @mmd which helped me dig deeper into Overpass API and REST calls.

**EDIT:** I found how to add `node`, `way` and `rel`:

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=area[name="Heidelberg"]->.a;(node(area.a)[amenity=hospital];way(area.a)[amenity=hospital];rel(area.a)[amenity=hospital];);out;
```

Comment: The reason why you don't get any results for Italy is, that Italy is called "Italia" in Italian :) see https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/365331